# Text box disabled on the client side still enabled on the server side

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, customvalidator

In ASP.NET a `RequiredFieldValidator` still validates a textbox control even if I disabled it on the client-side. I wanted to get rid of this behavior by using a `CustomValidator`. In the validation function I check if the text box is enabled. If that is the case I set the validator to valid.

```
function ValidateTextBox(sender, args) {

    var $textbox = $('#txtFoo')
    args.isValid = $textbox.prop('disabled') || $textbox.val();

}
```

This works fine on the client-side. The problem is, that I changed the state of the text box on the client-side using JavaScript. The server therefore does not know about the changed state (that the textbox control is disabled now). So when the `ServerValidate` event of the custom validator is raised (by calling `Page.Validate` for example) I cannot check whether the text box is disabled or not. Because the server does not know about this the `Enabled` property is always set to true, no matter what I do on the client-side.
How can I disable validation for controls when they are disabled or tell the server the state of the text box during `Postback`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can the server tell from the state of the other controls (or the rest of the page) whether the textbox would have been disabled on client-side? The safest way to validate is just going to be duplicating the logic you currently have client-side, since all client-side script and form values can be changed via common debugging tools, anyway.

Comment: Surely this would work. I am using user controls to combine label input field and validator into one control. It would be nice if the control could handle that automatically without having to depend on the code of the page it is used on. I mean thats the advantage of the ASP.NET validation controls. You don't have to check the state of each of the controls manually. You just have to call Page.Validate and all is good.

Comment: When changing the value of a text box with JavaScript the server knows about that, because its value will be posted back to the server. Is it possible to use this mechanism to additionally send the disabled state of the text box together with its value?

Comment: I did not check if this works, because a quick solution was to change the state of the controls on the server during post back. The project is finished now, but perhaps a solution would be to use a HTML5 data attribute to render the client-side ID of the validator for a control. When disabling the control on the client-side you could call the function ValidatorEnable and pass the ID of the validator stored in the data attribute. If this will disable the validator on the server-side too, then the problem is solved, otherwise meh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of making `'disabled'` try to set textbox to `'ReadOnly'` mode.
2. You can `Enable` or `Disable` your `RequiredFieldValidator` at the time of you are disabling the textbox using `ValidatorEnable` JavaScript method 
   ([reference](http://manjuhpt.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/how-to-enabledisable-required-field-validator-in-javascript/))